# Getting list of device ringtones, weird error on 1 emulator?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume external_primary not found

But this only happens on 1 emulator I am running. It works fine on other emulators or my physical android phone.

Here is the code I am trying to run that causes the issue:

```
private fun listRingtones(): LinkedHashMap<String, String> {
    var manager = RingtoneManager(this)
    manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    var cursor: Cursor = manager.cursor
    var list = LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        var title: String = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
        var ringtoneURI: Uri = manager.getRingtoneUri(cursor.position)
        // Place the title and uri into a hashMap
        list.put(title, ringtoneURI.toString())
    }
    return list
}
```

Specifically the debugger craps out on this line:

```
var cursor: Cursor = manager.cursor
```

Anyone seen anything like this or what could be the cause?

Here is the full error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package.mypackage, PID: 7370
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume external_primary not found
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
    at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:3111)
    at android.media.RingtoneManager.query(RingtoneManager.java:646)
    at android.media.RingtoneManager.getMediaRingtones(RingtoneManager.java:579)
    at android.media.RingtoneManager.getMediaRingtones(RingtoneManager.java:571)
    at android.media.RingtoneManager.getCursor(RingtoneManager.java:437)
    at com.package.mypackage.NewReminderActivity.listRingtones(NewReminderActivity.kt:899)
    at com.package.mypackage.NewReminderActivity.access$listRingtones(NewReminderActivity.kt:61)
    at com.package.mypackage.NewReminderActivity$showSoundMenuAlert$2.onClick(NewReminderActivity.kt:1120)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```